# A better way of writing exponents/superscripts for matrices?

Tags: subscripts, superscripts, size

[image]

How can I make the height of the left-hand side (Sigma with superscript) and the right-hand side(Lambda with an exponent 1/2) the same or at least to a similar level?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% vector notation
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
%\section{Introduction}
\begin{equation}\label{eq.xCovPc}
    \vec{\Sigma}_{12}^{mc}=\vec{V}_1\vec{\Lambda}_1^{\frac{1}{2}}\vec{R}\vec{\Lambda}_2^{\frac{1}{2}}\vec{V}_2'
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a way, I'm surprised that your main concern with the equation appears to lie with the appearance of the `\frac{1}{2}` terms. I would prioritize fixing (a) the poor kerning of the superscript terms associated with `\vec{\Lambda}`, (b) the poor kerning of the subscript terms associated with `\vec{V}`, and (c) the fact that the vertical position of the subscript in `\vec{V}_1` differs notably from that of all other subscript terms. I've highlighted them in the first row of the followings screenshot; they're fixed in rows 2 and3.

If, after fixing these issues, you still don't like the appearance of the `\frac{1}{2}` terms, you can replace them with with `0.5` or `1/2`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
    
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
\vec{\Sigma}_{12}^{mc} = \vec{V}_1 \vec{\Lambda}_1^{\frac{1}{2}} \vec{R} \vec{\Lambda}_2^{\frac{1}{2}} \vec{V}_2' \\      
\vec{\Sigma}_{12}^{\mathrm{mc}} = \vec{V}^{}_{\!1} \vec{\Lambda}_1^{\!0.5}\vec{R}\vec{\Lambda}_2^{\!0.5} \vec{V}_{\!2}' \\
\vec{\Sigma}_{12}^{\mathrm{mc}} = \vec{V}^{}_{\!1} \vec{\Lambda}_1^{\mkern-5mu 1/2} \vec{R} \vec{\Lambda}_2^{\mkern-5mu 1/2} \vec{V}_{\!2}'
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are absolutely right. I was totally ignorant of kerning!

Answer (score 1):

Is this, obtained with the `relsize` package, more like you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}

% vector notation
\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq.xCovPc}
    \mathlarger{\vec{\Sigma}}_{12}^{mc}=\vec{V}_1\mathlarger{\vec{\Lambda}}_1^{\!\frac{1}{2}}\vec{R}\mathlarger{\vec{\Lambda}}_2^{\!\frac{1}{2}}\vec{V}_2'
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the advice. I understood somehow we can manually adjust the font size with the relsize package :)